Is existence of this function on nonempty sets of Quine atoms consistent with ZF-Regularity?
Working in $\sf ZF \text { - Regularity}$
Let $A $ be the set of all Quine atoms.
Let $f$ be a partial injective function from $\mathcal P(A)\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ to $A$.
Lets postulate the existing of exactly one atom that is not in the range of $f$.

Is the following principle consistent?


if $\psi$ is an $\sf FOL(=,\in)$ formula, whose free variables are "$a,w_1,\ldots,w_n$"; then:

$$n=1,2,3,\ldots \\\forall \operatorname {atoms} w_1  ,\ldots, w_n   , \forall x\in \mathcal P(A)\setminus \{\emptyset\}: \\ x=\{a \in A \mid \psi\} \to \exists y: f(x)=y$$

if the above is consistent, can $f$ be allowed in the above schema provided that each atomic subformula of $\psi$ in which $f$ occurs must be of the form $f(\cdot)= w_i$?


Yes, this is consistent.
Here is one way to build a model. Start in a transitive model of ZFC with some $V_\kappa\prec V$. Now interpret a model $V[\![A]\!]$ with countably many urelements $A=\{a_n\mid n\in\omega\}$. Turn them into Quine atoms.
Since $V_\kappa[\![A]\!]\prec V[\![A]\!]$, there is a truth predicate for subsets of $A$ using parameters from $A$, since truth in $V[\![A]\!]$ is the same as $V_\kappa[\![A]\!]$, which is a set and hence has a truth predicate. So the model will have a listing of the definable subsets of $A$ with those kinds of parameters.
Finally, since there are only countably many formulas and countably many parameters from $A$, we can inject the definable subsets of $A$ into $A$, leaving exactly one atom out of the range.

just to make sure, does this answer the second question I mean when $f$ is allowed in the sense given there?

No, just the first question, since I am choosing the injection after I list the definable sets. Not sure how to handle $f$ also as a parameter, and wouldn't be surprised if it is inconsistent to do that. But I don't think I have time to think about it...

if $f$ is put as a parameter in unrestricted manner, then of course it is inconsistent, a paradox like Russell's would be immediate. But, I tried to bar this inconsistency by limiting the formulation in which $f$ occurs in the way I presented. Hoping this can work.
